# Plotly does not know 'bar' type in react-js with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plotly

I am trying to run a minimal working example of using a plotly bar char in an React JS project with typescript but I get typescript errors complaining that 'bar' is not a valid option. It is/should be and the example works in a non-typescript React project.

This is error I get - it complains about some violin data type which does not make sense to me:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: PlotParams | Readonly<PlotParams>): Plot', gave the following error.
    Type '{ x: number[]; y: number[]; type: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Data[]'.
      Type '{ x: number[]; y: number[]; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Data'.
        Type '{ x: number[]; y: number[]; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ViolinData>'.
          Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"violin"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PlotParams, context: any): Plot', gave the following error.
    Type '{ x: number[]; y: number[]; type: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Data[]'.
```

This my code piece

```
import React from "react";
import Plot from "react-plotly.js";

function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      x: [1, 2, 3],
      y: [100, 50, 300],
      type: "bar",
      name: "Health",
    },
  ];
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Plot data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I managed to remove the typescript error by using `type: "bar" as const` and `<Plot data={data} layout={{}} />`. Not sure if there are any other problems, though.